# How can I make the find function not display anything on the command line?

Tags: batch-file, find, windows-task-scheduler

Here's what I got:

```
SCHTASKS /query /tn "test" | find /c "Running" &&(
goto finish
)||(
SCHTASKS /create /tn "test" /sc minute /mo 10 /tr c:\bin\go.vbs
)

:finish
echo.
echo Done
echo.
timeout 3
```

I want to check to see if the `test` task is already running. The functionality of this works, but even with echo off, the find /c part keeps returning either a 1 or a 0, depending on if the task was running or not.

Is there a way I can make it so that it isn't printing out a 1 or a 0 whenever I run it in the command line?

Answer (score 0):

```
| find /c "Running">Nul 2>&1&&(
```

Make your change as above.

Your script may be better like this too:

```
SCHTASKS /query /tn "test" | find /c "Running">Nul 2>&1&&(goto :finish)
SCHTASKS /create /tn "test" /sc minute /mo 10 /tr c:\bin\go.vbs

:finish
echo.
echo Done
echo.
timeout 3
```

Comment: while it doesn't display 1's and 0's, it does give `ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.` When I first run it.

Comment: My answer was a solution to your specific question. You stated that your script was working, I have added nothing which can affect the script such that it can output the error you are reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this:

```
SCHTASKS /query  | findstr /n "test" &&(
goto finish
)||(
SCHTASKS /create /tn "test" /sc minute /mo 10 /tr c:\bin\go.vbs
)

:finish
echo.
echo Done
echo.
timeout 3
```